# Firebase for multiplayer games - verify data that is sent to the database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm starting to learn about google's firebase, seems really cool for real time applications. The auto-synced database seems very easy to use and I feel like diving into it.. I plan to start learning by building a simple checkers multiplayer game, but I still have an important question about it..

Firebase auto-syncs between users and devices using their 'magic' Database, which stores data and sends out to 'subscribers' of that db. Now what if I want to have some server processing of this data in between? For example, when a player makes a move, I want something that is not on client-side to make sure that is a valid move.. what would be the architecture to accomplish that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having a trusted process that sits between the users is a common scenario when using Firebase. Have a look at our classic blog post [Where does Firebase fit in your app?](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/03/where-does-firebase-fit-in-your-app.html), it would fit closest to pattern 2 there.

Typically you'll want to use the [firebase-queue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-queue) for this. Your users write their "requests" (probably moves in your case) into the queue, the server processes those and updates the actual board.

Another great thing about this is that it's easy to secure. The users can only write to the queue, while the server is the only one that can read the queue and update the board. A lot simpler to capture in [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/) than many other approaches.